# How do I increase the width of each tab in order for them to occupy the whole width of the content block?

Tags: html, css, tabs, width

I'm fairly new to programming and this site but I've been studying different codes for vertical and horizontal tabs and there's a questions I want to ask regarding this one https://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/812ehkyf/ :

Basically, I've been trying to change the width of the tabs in order for them to occupy the whole width of the content block below, however I wasn't able to do it, what should i add/change? Adding width: 200px; in .tab or .tab label doesn't seem to work.

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 35px 0 25px;
  background: white;
}

.tab {
  float: left;       
}

.tab label {
   background: #eee; 
   padding: 10px; 
   border: 1px solid #ccc; 
   margin-left: -1px; 
   position: relative;
   left: 1px; 
   top: -29px;
   -webkit-transition: background-color .17s linear;
}
```

It would be nice if a detailed explanation is provided on the changes or additions so I can understand it well. 
A way with the use of javascript was found, however, is it possible to only uses css and html?

Answer (score 0):

See first of your body padding is so high.

so may be i think you have to decrease it.

```
body {
   background: #999;  
   padding: 20px 2px; 
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 35px 0 25px;
  background: white;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set your tabs width to  - 33%

```js
  function openTab(tabId) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById(tabId).style.display = "block";
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openTab('TabA')">TabA</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openTab('TabB')">TabB</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openTab('TabC')">TabC</button>
</div>

<div id="TabA" class="w3-container tab">
 <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
       
       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab One</p>
       </div> 
</div>

<div id="TabB" class="w3-container tab" style="display:none">
   <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
       
       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab Two</p>
           
           <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100">
       </div> 
</div>

<div id="TabC" class="w3-container tab" style="display:none">
 <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>
     
       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab Three</p>
           
           <img src="http://placedog.com/200/100">
       </div> 
</div>
<style> .w3-bar .w3-button{
    width:33.3%;
    }</style>
```